# Add span to contenteditable div at cursor position

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Textarea Suggestions</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <button id="addButton">Add</button>
    <div class="textarea-container">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    let count = 0;
    let firstBackspacePressed = false;
    let suggestion_selected=""
    let cposition=0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
      let textareaCount = 0; // To keep track of added textareas

      const addButton = $("#addButton");
      addButton.click(function () {
        textareaCount++;
        const textareaId = textareaCount // Generate a unique id
        const textareaHtml = `<div class="textarea-item"><div class="edit" role="textbox"  contenteditable="true" id="${textareaId}"></div><ul class="autocomplete-list"></ul></div>`;
        $(".textarea-container").append(textareaHtml);
      });

      let textareaValues = [];
    
      $(".textarea-container").on("input", ".edit", function (e) {
        const div = $(this);
        
        const caretPosition = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
        const newValue=div.text();
        if(e.keyCode===8){
          console.log(caretPosition)
          const updatedValue = newValue.substring(newValue.indexOf("<>"), newValue.lastIndexOf("'<>"));
          return div.textContent=updatedValue
        }
        
        const suggestionsList = div.next(".autocomplete-list");
        const value = div.text();
        console.log('Value',value)
        const lastBracketIndex = value.lastIndexOf("<>", caretPosition);
        count=lastBracketIndex
        console.log('Count',count)
        // Update textareaValues with current div's value
        const index = $(".textarea-container .edit").index(div);
        textareaValues[index] = value;

        if (lastBracketIndex !== -1) {
          const filterText = value.substring(lastBracketIndex + 2, caretPosition);
          console.log(lastBracketIndex, filterText);

          // Include updated div values in suggestions, excluding the current div being edited                                     
          const suggestionArr = textareaValues
            .filter((item, idx) => idx !== index && item.includes(filterText))
            .map(item => item);

          const suggestionItems = suggestionArr.map(suggestion => `<li>${suggestion}</li>`).join("");
          suggestionsList.html(suggestionItems);
          suggestionsList.show();
        } else {
          suggestionsList.empty();
          suggestionsList.hide();
        }
      });
  
   //This function!  
  $(".textarea-container").on("click", ".autocomplete-list li", function () {
  const selectedSuggestion = $(this).text();
  const div = $(this).closest(".textarea-item").find(".edit");

  // Find the caret position
  const caretPosition = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;

  // Insert the selected suggestion at the cursor position
  const currentValue = div.text();
  const newValue =
    currentValue.slice(0, caretPosition) +
    selectedSuggestion +
    currentValue.slice(caretPosition);

  div.text(newValue);

  // Hide the suggestions dropdown
  $(this).closest(".autocomplete-list").empty().hide();
});
      $(".textarea-container").on("keydown", ".edit", function (e) {

        
  const div = $(this);
  let id = $(this).attr('id')
  const value = div.text();
  const caretPosition = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startOffset;
        const lastBracketIndex = value.lastIndexOf("<>", caretPosition);  
    var pos=(0+caretPosition-(suggestion_selected.length+2))
       const matchingSubstring = textareaValues.slice(0,-1)
      .find(item => item.includes("<>"+value) );
if(value.includes('<>')){
  if (event.key === 'Backspace' || event.key === 'Delete') {
    if (firstBackspacePressed) {
      firstBackspacePressed=false;
      // Allow default behavior (delete text) on the second backspace
      $(this).unbind('keydown');
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
      if(value.substring(lastBracketIndex,caretPosition).indexOf(" ")==-1){
    //  selectText(lastBracketIndex,caretPosition,id);
  } 
      firstBackspacePressed = true;
    }
  }}
  })
    }); 

  function selectText(start, end, id) {
const range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(document.getElementById(id).firstChild, start);
range.setEnd(document.getElementById(id).firstChild, end);

const selection = window.getSelection();
selection.removeAllRanges();
selection.addRange(range);
}

// Function to delete the currently selected text
function deleteSelectedText() { 
const selection = window.getSelection();
if (!selection.isCollapsed) {
  selection.deleteFromDocument();
}
}
function insertTextAtCursor(text) { 
            var sel, range, html; 
            sel = window.getSelection();
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0); 
            range.deleteContents(); 
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
            range.insertNode(textNode);
            range.setStartAfter(textNode);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);        
        }
        function keyHandle(evt) {
            key = evt.keyCode;
            switch(key) {
                case 9: //Tab
                    insertTextAtCursor('\t');
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    break
                case 13: //Enter
                    insertTextAtCursor('\n');
                    evt.preventDefault();
                    break
            }
        }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My click function is not inserting the element chosen from the dropdown at the cursor position after . The suggestion box is displayed on typing "<>" in the div. Wrapping the element in span seems to mess up the position at which it is inserted it. Basically its an autocomplete feature where one div inherits value of the other divs on typing "<>" and selecting. Can anyone help with this functionality, thank you! I am using span so i can colour the selected suggestion later on insertion.

Answer (score 0):

I did not analyse your code, but the following snippet illustrates how you can insert a span at the cursor position:

```js
function insertSpan() {
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  span.style.color = "red";
  var r = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  r.surroundContents(span);
  span.textContent = "<insert text>";
  document.querySelector("div").focus();
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable>Your text here</div>
<button onclick="insertSpan()">Insert span</button>
```

After inserting a `<span>`, if you want to type text that comes *after* the span (and is therefore not colored), you must ensure that the cursor is outside of the `<span>`. You cannot directly control this, but as a workaround, first insert a "placeholder":

| Action | What to type | Effect |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Place cursor (`|`) at the end of the text | <kbd>end</kbd> | `Your text here|` |
| Add a placeholder after the cursor | <kbd>.</kbd>, <kbd>left arrow</kbd> | `Your text here|.` |
| Insert a `<span>` | Press button | `Your text here [<insert text>].` |
| Overtype the text in the `<span>` | Type the text | `Your text here <colored text>|.` |
| [Select] the "placeholder" | <kbd>shift+right arrow</kbd> | `Your text here <colored text>[.]` |
| Overtype the selection with uncolored text | Type the text | `Your text here <colored text><uncolored text>` |

Comment: Hey @Heiko Theißen, Thanks for the code! Im running into the same problem in that, the text i type after the span insertion is also the same color as the span. Any idea how to reset it to default color after span insertion!

Comment: That's a bit tricky, see my augmented answer.